# Is there a way to return a list of records which match an attribute of the first query filter result using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, repository-pattern

I have a list of records where their uniqueness is based of a string (name) and languageID (ForeignKey)

I have the ID (PK) which I use in the query filter e.g.

```
Video = _videoRepository.Get(v => v.ID == parameterID && v.Guid == ` 
_currentUser.Guid).FirstOrDefault();`
```

This of course will return one matching record, however I have a use case where I have multiple 'Videos' with the same name but different languageIDs, and in this case would like to return all of them e.g.

```
Name = '*videoName*', LanguageID = 1,
Name = '*videoName*', LanguageID = 2,
Name = '*videoName*', LanguageID = 3,
Name = '*videoName*', LanguageID = 4...
```

So essentially want to be able to return the one matching the '*parameterID*' as well as all those which match its name attribute.

I know this could be done using separate repository calls, getting the first match and then using it to return any records which match its name but I would like to do this in the same query. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: My first guess would be that you use the GroupBy() LINQ extension method.

Comment: Do you try to change the repository, if so can you share it? if _videoRepository is just a table please write it.

Answer (score 0):

say you have a collection, like a List videoList = new List();

That you yanked out of a _videoRepository.GetAll()? Maybe ?

all you would need to do is:

var subSet = videoList.Where(v => v.Name.Equals("NameToSearchFor"));

now if you want to do it directly on your repository, it isn't harder than implementing a GetBy() parameter, that returns a list, and then correlating it to an implementation on your IO component that gets a list.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. Yeah, if i had the Name of the first object i would be home and dry, but all i have to work with is the Primary Key. So as i was saying, i could return a single record based on this, then perform a secondary call returning everything that matches the name of the first result, I just ideally would like to do it in one query.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, in order to have the primary key from OUTSIDE the IO layer, you must have originally queried the DB for the primary key.

When you got that row, at any one point, ALSO retrieve the name on the item...

Thus when you do the "by name" query, you don't have to actually remember the primary key in your logic, 

Which, if you wrote proper code, you wouldn't have in your domain layer anyway. 

You are never supposed to have PK and FK, OUTSIDE the boundary of an IO layer. 
Simply because your domain logic should be clear of any possible internal logic in them.

Comment: your Repository might need it internally, to identify unique rows from colleciton results, but the ID, should not exist on your domain logic object, it should be "mapped" out, before your object leaves the repo.

Say you want to use a NoSQL database for your repo instead? If your domain logic demands PK/FK, you are up shit creek, and no paddle.

Comment: The ID i use to query is a foreign key on a separate object, its literally just the ID. I haven't queried the Video table at all at this point. So i have an ID, which i want to use to query a table of existing Video records, return the one which matches this ID, along with all other records which match the Name attribute of it.

Comment: Ah, I think what confused me here is that you Get(v => v.id ... )
Okay, yeah no, there is no way to do a group by, or any other call that in one execution will grant you the "where" effect of a property on a single row column combination, and THEN filter by said combination WITHOUT executing two queries towards the database.

Because, you will have to obtain the value out of the PK first, before you can request a sub-set from said value

I mean you could create a stored procedure that does this in two steps on the DB itself, so you only make one request to the db...

But you execute 2

Comment: Yeah its hard to convey context well here. Its my first question on here, going forward i will do better lol! So the only way to do this is get the first result, then use its Name to return all other matches in a separate call? I thought this may be the case, but calling the same repository twice in succession just didn't feel right!

Comment: your request doesn't really make sense. 

Say you have:

Name = Neo, Language = EN, UserId = 1
Name = Neo, Language = DE UserId = 2
Name = Neo, Language = FR UserId = 1
Name = LionKing, Language = DK UserId = 1
Name = Lionking Language = DE UserId = 2

And you want to find all language, for a specific movie title, based on users Id: 

if you group by title, you will have to concat language ID's into a field, that could work I suppose, but you would then have to string split them in the repo itself. 

It again, doesn't make sense that you claim you have a Video PK?

Comment: Having a user PK, could result in many video names, Like "LionKing", "Neo", "Santas Happy day off", etc, for a single user, you would indeed NOT be guaranteed a single result. 

You would required to handle that a user can have many videos, and many language versions, not a single result. Only a PK would on the video would make it unique.

Comment: Try to build a LIST of the object type you have in C#, like 


list.Add(new Item { Name = "*videoName*", LanguageID = 1, UserId = 1 });
            list.Add(new Item { Name = "*videoName*", LanguageID = 2, UserId = 1 });
            list.Add(new Item { Name = "*videoName*", LanguageID = 3 UserId = 1});
            list.Add(new Item { Name = "*videoName*", LanguageID = 4 UserId = 2});

but populate it more, way more examples, and I think you will realize, that you are thinking about your problem all wrong. 
Either you entry is incorrect, or your result, isn't what you claim.

Comment: Please provide an Integration test, or Unit test example, that displays what you are trying to do, and what error the test is giving you, this will give us MUCH MORE clarification to help you

Comment: So for that use case i have a NotMapped virtual int list 'AvailableLanguageIDs' which when needed is populated using the name. The reason i have only the PK of the video is because this is part of a course, which has sections, and contents within can be matched to a video, or a piece of audio, or a doc etc, so depending on what type the content within the section is it will or wont have a VideoID. Anyways, thanks for your help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you would like to find all IDs that match the VideoName. Grouping the data by VideoName in that case is the solution. The code below will result in one item that contains all the LanguageIDs for the VideoName. Is that what you are looking for?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace RemoveChars
{
    internal class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Class holding your videonames and languageID
        /// </summary>
        public class Item
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }    
            public int LanguageID { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Creating a list of all Videonames and LanguageIDs
            List<Item> list = new List<Item>();

            list.Add(new Item { Name = "*videoName*", LanguageID = 1 });
            list.Add(new Item { Name = "*videoName*", LanguageID = 2 });
            list.Add(new Item { Name = "*videoName*", LanguageID = 3 });
            list.Add(new Item { Name = "*videoName*", LanguageID = 4 });

            // Now get a result grouping the list by its item.Name (videoname).
            var result = list.GroupBy(item => item.Name).ToList();

            // Printout the result
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                // The Key holds the videoname
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key);

                // The item holds the IDs in that group.
                foreach (var id in item)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(id.LanguageID);
                }
            }
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Result is:

```
*videoName*
1
2
3
4
```